# WPForms start date next week

Tags: php, wordpress

For the WPForms Date & Time I need a function that allows selecting only from next week on wards.

For example if we are on Wednesday, you could only pick dates starting from next week Monday.

Or if we are on Sunday, still next week Monday.

Maybe on this link you can find something helpful:
https://wpforms.com/developers/customize-the-date-time-field-date-options/

So far I've tried to play with the "minDate" and "maxDate" but been only able to get it work so it will let me pick the day after 7 days.

So if we are on Sunday it wouldn't let me pick the next week dates.

**List of codes I've tried with no success:**

```
/**
 * Limit the dates available in the Date Time date picker: Block out certain date ranges
 *
 * @link https://wpforms.com/developers/customize-the-date-time-field-date-options/
 */
 
function wpf_limit_date_picker() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var today = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5;
        var weekFromToday = today.setDate(today.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);

        var month = today.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var day = today.getUTCDate();
        var year = today.getUTCFullYear():
        var todayString = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

        var weekFromTodayMonth = weekFromToday.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var weekFromTodayDay = weekFromToday.getUTCDate();
        var weekFromTodayYear = weekFromToday.getUTCFullYear();
        var weekFromTodayString = `${weekFromTodayYear}-${weekFromTodayMonth}-${weekFromTodayDay}`;

        window.wpforms_datepicker = {
          disableMobile: true,
          // Don't allow users to pick specific range of dates
           disable: [
            {
              from: todayString,
                to: weekFromTodayString
            }
         ]
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_limit_date_picker', 10 );
```

```
/**
 * Limit the dates available in the Date Time date picker: Block out certain date ranges
 *
 * @link https://wpforms.com/developers/customize-the-date-time-field-date-options/
 */
 
function wpf_limit_date_picker() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date();
        var startDate = new Date();
        var endDate = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7));

        window.wpforms_datepicker = {
            disableMobile: true,
            // Don't allow users to pick specific range of dates
            disable: [
                {
                    from: startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                    to: endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                }
            ]
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_limit_date_picker', 10 );
```

```
/**
 * Limit the dates available in the Date Time date picker: Block out certain date ranges
 *
 * @link https://wpforms.com/developers/customize-the-date-time-field-date-options/
 */
 
function wpf_limit_date_picker() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date();
        window.wpforms_datepicker = {
            disableMobile: true,
            // Don't allow users to pick specific range of dates
            minDate: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7)
            ]
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_limit_date_picker', 10 );
```

```
/**
 * Limit the dates available in the Date Time date picker: Block out certain date ranges
 *
 * @link https://wpforms.com/developers/customize-the-date-time-field-date-options/
 */
 
function wpf_limit_date_picker() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date();
        window.wpforms_datepicker = {
            disableMobile: true,
            // Don't allow users to pick specific range of dates
            minDate: new Date().fp_incr(7)
            ]
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_limit_date_picker', 10 );
```

Comment: Can you share some code so we can see where you might be going wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.